# Set 'nofollow' in Yoast, for Woocommerce product pages in a specific category

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, seo, yoast

I have been trying to exclude a specific "wholesaler-category"(b2b_only) from being indexed.
Bellow code seems to be ignored by Yoast. Or as far as I can see in the meta header, the products are still in index and follow.

```
add_filter( 'wpseo_googlebot', 'yoast_seo_robots_remove_single' );
add_filter( 'wpseo_bingbot', 'yoast_seo_robots_remove_single' );
add_filter( 'wpseo_robots', 'yoast_seo_robots_remove_single' );

function yoast_seo_robots_remove_single( $robots ) {
    if ( is_product() && has_term( 'b2b_only' ) ) { //check for b2b category
    return 'noindex,nofollow'; //noindex nofollow this product
    }
    
    else {
    return $robots; //else return robots
    }

}
```

I am not sure, if it is WP or Yoast that is overruling this. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: have you attempted to set nofollow inside actual
product > > categories >> b2b_only page in the menu because yoast has a settings window on a per category basis

Comment: Yes. This sets no follow for the category page only. Not for the products itself.